# Exception handling Camel Apache

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel, salesforce

I'm new to Camel Apache and I'm having some troubles in the Exception handling.
What I'm trying to do is catch the SalesforceException and from there I need to take different actions based on the statusCode.

For example, when the statusCode >= 500 I must try to redeliver the message. This is a technical error.
When the statusCode < 500, I must combine the request & response and place it on the failureQueue.

So my question is : **how can I try to redeliver the message in a choice definition?** It doesn't seem possible to use the following options you can use on onException :

```
          .handled(true).useOriginalMessage().maximumRedeliveries(3)
          .redeliveryDelay(5000)
          .logRetryAttempted(true)
          .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
```

I also tried throwing new exceptions I defined myself so I can handle it from there but then it looks like the FatalFallbackErrorHandler takes over and I have no power as I can't handle it by myself.
So my second question - if there's no answer to resending it in a choicedefinition - **how can I handle it in a custom exception without the ErrorHandler taking over?**

Here is my code :

```
    onException()
         .logStackTrace(true);


    onException(SalesforceException.class)
                .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    SalesforceException cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, SalesforceException.class);
                    exchange.setProperty("statusCode", cause.getStatusCode());
                    exchange.setProperty("response", cause.getMessage());
                }
            })
            .choice()
                .when(header("statusCode").isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(500))
        // try to redeliverd the orginal message
                    .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "{{logger}}", "Salesforce exception caught with statusCode >= 500")
                    .throwException(new SalesforceTechnicalException()) 
                .otherwise()
        // combine request & response and put on failurequeue
                    .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "{{logger}}", "Salesforce exception caught with statusCode < 500, following message will be put on failure queue")                                                  
                    .throwException(new SalesforceFunctionalException())     
            .end();

    onException(SalesforceTechnicalException.class)
    //combine request & response and put on failurequeue
            .transform(ExpressionBuilder.simpleExpression("{\"request\" : ${exchangeProperty.requestBody}, \"response\" : ${exchangeProperty.response}}"))
            .to("log:{{logger}}?level=INFO&showHeaders=true")
            .to("amqp:qFailure?exchangePattern=InOnly");

    onException(SalesforceTechnicalException.class)
    //try resending the orginal message to SF Rest API
            .useOriginalMessage()
            .handled(true)
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(5000)
            .logRetryAttempted(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a pair of onException(SalesforceException.class) blocks and narrow each one with an onWhen(Predicate).

```
    onException(SalesforceException.class)
        .onWhen(new Predicate() {

            @Override
            public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                SalesforceException cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, SalesforceException.class);
                return cause.getStatusCode() < 500;
            }
        })
        .log("Handled here if statusCode < 500")
        .useOriginalMessage()
        .handled(true)
        .maximumRedeliveries(3)
        .redeliveryDelay(5000)
        .logRetryAttempted(true);

    onException(SalesforceException.class)
        .onWhen(new Predicate() {

            @Override
            public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                SalesforceException cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, SalesforceException.class);
                return cause.getStatusCode() >= 500;
            }
        })
        .log("Handled here if statusCode >= 500")
        .transform(ExpressionBuilder.simpleExpression("{\"request\" : ${exchangeProperty.requestBody}, \"response\" : ${exchangeProperty.response}}"))
        .to("log:{{logger}}?level=INFO&showHeaders=true")
        .to("amqp:qFailure?exchangePattern=InOnly");
```